# Is there a way we can fetch data once Google Sheets is edited or updated using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi I want to check in the Google Sheet data after edit and send the data to a phone android app using appscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the provided [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedit), specifically the `onEdit` trigger.

> `onEdit(e)` runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.

You can view the values of the `e` event parameter [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). You are likely to be the most interested in the `oldValue` and `value` fields of the edit event. In your script you'll have something like :

```js
function onEdit(event) {
    let old = event.oldValue;
    let new = event.value;
    let message = `value changed from {old} to {new}`

    // send message to phone
}
```

As far as actually sending the message to a phone you will probably want to open a new separate question sense I don't think there is a simple or obvious solution. The only built in methods sending messages to external services are via gmail, http requests to an external server the app can access, and possibly dumping edit events into another sheet which the app can access.